# I used Spring Data JPA to create a table in MySQL, but the creation failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I used Spring Data JPA to create a table in MySQL, but the creation failed. I can't find the error in my entity class, and I think the configuration is not wrong.

I changed some jdbc connection statements in the properties, as well as annotations on the entity class, but it didn't work.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Column
    private String password;

}
```

properties file is as follows:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=localhost # Spring Data Jpa 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or exceptions in the console? Can you provide connection details?

Comment: # MySQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=localhost

# Spring Data Jpa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Comment: this is my properties file

Comment: Error executing DDL "create table article (id varchar(255) not null auto_increment, author Bleibtreu, category varchar(255), content varchar(255), photo_url varchar(255), time datetime, title varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

Comment: this is my error code

Comment: How can `varchar` be autoincremented? I suggest you change it to for example `integer`.

Comment: yes,i change id to int,but this quesiton don't solve.

Comment: Where is article entity ?

Comment: They are similar, but the stack overflow does not let me enter.

Comment: Try adding `spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` instead of `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` instead of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`.

Comment: Change also `id` in `User` class from `String` to `int`.

Comment: There are three tables created, but there are still two tables that fail. I found an error like this: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: I get it ! It is "columnDefinition = ' '  ",but ,i don't know why?

Comment: I found that the table with this annotation was not created successfully @Column(columnDefinition="https://weibo.com/")

Comment: so i delete this Annotated attribute，is ok。

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: @SudhirOjha The dash-separated properties are correct for Spring Boot and an alternative to the camelcase variant.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, `id` should always be of type `Long`. Please change that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how a **String** can be auto-incremented, it's better to change it to **Long** or **int**.